# Python Script to get attachments from gmail account

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

This code runs and does download the attachments as expected.
That said, It writes all attachments to the directory on my PC. I only want to include an attachment with a .html file type. Anything else should be omitted.
Secondly, I would like it to only import the .html attachment if the subject line = "Whatever" if this is true then I would like it to save to a specific subfolder in the PC directory. So for example: if subject = "Whatever1" then save to c:\Desktop\Folder\Subfolder1, if subject = "Whatever2" then save to c:\Desktop\Folder\Subfolder2 etc

```
import email, imaplib, os

#Credentials
username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'

#SaveTo Directory on PC 
attachment_dir = "C:/Desktop\Folder\Subfolder"

#Functions
def get_body(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(None,True)

def get_attachments(msg):
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype()=='multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-disposition') is None:
            continue
        filename = part.get_filename()

        if bool(filename) :
            filepath =os.path.join(attachment_dir, filename)
            with open(filepath,'wb')as f:
                f.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))


def search(key,value,mail):
    result, data = mail.search(none,key,'"()"'.format(value))
    return data
def get_emails(result_bytes):
    msgs = []
    for num in result_bytes[0].split():
        typ,data = mail.fetch(num,'(RCF822)')
        msgs.append(data)
    return msgs

#Create Connection
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
mail.login(username, password) 

#Which Gmail Folder to Select?
mail.select("Inbox")

result, data = mail.fetch(b'12','(RFC822)')
raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
get_attachments(raw)
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-attachment-gmail-account-using-python/

Comment: Not really, although some good context in there

Answer (score 2):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox

# get all attachments from INBOX and save them to files
with MailBox('imap.my.ru').login('acc', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch():
        print(msg.subject)
        for att in msg.attachments:
            print('-', att.filename, att.content_type)
            with open('C:/1/{}'.format(att.filename), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(att.payload)
```

lib: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score -2):

```
for mList in range(numMessages):
        for msg in msg.startswith("Subject:")
            if msg.startswith('Subject'):
                print(msg)
                break
```

This should parse the subject line, so you can distinguish by whatever you want the subject to be.